# SQL Primary Key - set to one

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I'm adding a new item to my table, but they got wrong ID's! First I write the ID's manually but then I change to `Auto Increment` and delete all items of the table. Now the ID's starts , where my last were. How can I changed it to 1? Thank you!

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Just truncate your table and then add records if you are using sql server.

Comment: Hi thank you for answers. I'm using MySQL.

Comment: This works, but the table has to be empty.

Comment: just run this query in mysql: `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;` and you're good to go.